# Small C pointer issue

Tags: c, pointers

Will this set the user_id (which is an 'int' field (i.e. non-pointer)) in the (pointer to a) struct nodes[i] to have the value equal to the user_id in the struct users[i]?

```
nodes[i]->user_id = &users[i].user_id;
```

Or does this syntax work?

```
nodes[i]->user_id = users[i].user_id;
```

Clearly, I'm a bit confused about whether the left side is a pointer or a value here.

Comment: Thanks. That solves it. Just thought maybe even though the field was the same type I would have to use the first syntax because the first struct was a pointer.. But clearly not!

Comment: @txtechhelp: The first version is simply invalid. It is illegal to assign pointer values to integer objects in C.

Comment: @J...S: Considering that many modern C compilers have rather loose error checking and allow implicit pointer-to-integer conversions (with a mere warning), it is quite possible that both versions "worked" (i.e. at least "compiled").

Answer (score 1):

In C, a pointer is used to reference the address of the object in memory:

```
int *pointerToFirstIndexOfArray = users[0]; // The int * value now points to the location in memory
```

One uses the & value to grab the actual *value* of the address in memory, rather than just where the location is:

```
int a = 0;
int &b = a; // B is now a reference to A, since B is literally the address in memory of where A is located
```

Lastly, using -> is the shorthand notation of (*).:

```
(*users[i]).valueInsideUserStruct = someValue; // these statements are equal
users[i]->valueInsideUserStruct = someValue; // these statements are equal
```

C does this because it is easier to read var->val rather than (*var).val

To answer your question, the first code you posted only changes the value *to the address* (the operator & literally returns the address), while the second code you posted actually changes the value to the value *at the address*.